# The other TRON game

Tags: video-games, computers, tron

I'm looking for a computer version of the **OTHER** TRON game from the original film. Not the light cycle one, but the one played with discs on a circular light platform. If the contestants fail to catch the disc and the disc hits a circular region, the region disappears, so now the contestants have to jump over the gap.

Comment: Looking for it in what respect? Trying to find the name? Trying to find a copy of it?

Answer (score 2):

Found it - it's called 'Discs of Tron', 'Duel Discs' or 'Disc Battle'.

There's a Unity© version [here](http://disney.co.uk/disney-games/play/tron/disc-battle).

Comment: If you like the disc game, you should try Tron 2.0 from 2003. You play Jet Bradley, the son of Allen, and much of the combat is performed using your disc. It's a very fun romp through the Tron universe!